# Issue with newElements function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a vote function in one of my projects. Please see following code.

```
 $(function () {
    $(".vote").click(function () {
        var id = $(this).data("id");
        var name = $(this).data("name");
        var dataString = 'id=' + id;
        //var dataId = id;
        var parent = $(this);

        if (name == 'up') {
            $(this).fadeIn(200).html;
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "vote_up.php",
                data: dataString,
                cache: false,

                success: function (html) {
                    parent.parent().find(".display-vote").html(html);
                }
            });
        } else {
            $(this).fadeIn(200).html;
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "vote_down.php",
                data: dataString,
                cache: false,

                success: function (html) {
                    parent.parent().find(".display-vote").html(html);
                }
            });
        }
        return false;
    });
});
```

and I'm using `jQuery infinite scroll` to load rest of the pages/posts. I'm using following code in main page and second page which i load rest of the data

```
    ('#left').infinitescroll({
    navSelector: '#page-nav', // selector for the paged navigation 
    nextSelector: '#page-nav a', // selector for the NEXT link (to page 2)
    itemSelector: '.post-box', //


}, function (newElements, data, url) {

    $(".vote").click(function () {
        var id = $(this).data("id");
        var name = $(this).data("name");
        var dataString = 'id=' + id;
        //var dataId = id;
        var parent = $(this);

        if (name == 'up') {
            $(this).fadeIn(200).html;
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "vote_up.php",
                data: dataString,
                cache: false,

                success: function (html) {
                    parent.parent().find(".display-vote").html(html);
                }
            });
        } else {
            $(this).fadeIn(200).html;
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "vote_down.php",
                data: dataString,
                cache: false,

                success: function (html) {
                    parent.parent().find(".display-vote").html(html);
                }
            });
        }
        return false;
    });


});
```

Issue is after 2nd 3rd or any other page load, vote function is triggering twice. How can I fix this issue. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to unbind the click event before binding it again.

[...]

```
$(".vote").unbind('click').click(function()
```

[...]

or

[...]

```
$(".vote").off('click').click(function()
```

[..]

depending on the version of jQuery you are using.

Comment: I'm using jQuery 1.8.1. Can you please tell me in which place i should unbind click function?

Comment: function(newElements, data, url){

$(".vote").off("click").click(function()
{
var id = $(this).data("id");

Answer (score 3):

Maybe if you unbind the click event and then bind it

```
function(newElements, data, url){    
$(".vote").unbind( "click" ); 
$(".vote").click(function() {
```